# How to draw discontinued chart in C#

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

Now I'd like to draw a candlestick chart in C#. Problem I have is how to skip certain time of the x Axis. Say, the data starts from 9:00 and ends at 11:30. Then restart at 13:00 and ends in 15:00. If I fill data in it, period 11:30 to 13:00 will also be shown as a line. How to skip it and make it a consequence chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `series.IsXValueIndexed` to `true`, that should fix your problem

```
series.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

> All data points in a series use sequential indices, and if this
>   property is true then data points will be plotted sequentially,
>   regardless of their associated X-values. This means that there will be
>   no "missing" data points.

Take a look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but after setting series.IsXValueIndexed = true, it not worked for me. 
So I've found another way of achieving this.

```
series.XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
series.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```